# drupal_realpath not returning the correct path sometimes

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

When I try the below code in Drupal 7,

```
$imagePath = drupal_realpath('public://test_path');
print_r($imagePath);
```

It is giving the below output

> /Users//Sites/Drupal/sites/default/files/test_path

But when I execute the below code

```
$imagePath = drupal_realpath('public://test_path/test');
print_r($imagePath);
```

It is giving the output

> bool(false)

Why it is showing this behaviour? Is it possible to get the actual path in the second method?

Comment: If a folder doesn't exist , drupal_realpath return false , ensure your folder test exists or use file_prepare_directory before use it. Or you can use work around : `$imagePath = drupal_realpath('public://').'/test_path/test';` < but not recommended

Answer (score -1):

You can use `file_stream_wrapper_get_instance_by_uri` instead of `drupal_realpath()`

```
$dir_uri = file_stream_wrapper_get_instance_by_uri('public://test_path/test');
$dir_uri->realpath();
```